# How to force Nodejs v19+ to use TLS 1.2 to avoid write EPROTO SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure...SSL alert number 40

Tags: node.js, typescript, tls1.2, tls1.3

I am trying to get NodeJs to make get requests to a site that has disabled TLS 1.3. However, each request I make throws a handshake exception like the following:

`Error: write EPROTO 00683890CA7F0000:error:0A000410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1605:SSL alert number 40`

However, **if I downgrade to NodeJs v16.20.0, the request succeeds**.

You can see that the site in question has disabled TLS 1.3:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.legislation.gov.au&s=54.66.220.183

I have used printed the ciphers available in both v19 and v16 (using `tls.getCiphers()`) and have confirmed that the list of available ciphers is the same in both versions.

However, I have tried various permutations of setting the min and max TLS versions, creating httpsAgents, setting ciphers to use (both as a list and as '@SECLEVEL=1'), as well as trying the Node https client, axios and got, but so far, all to no avail.

Here is an example attempt to request the URL that **fails in v19** but **succeeds in v16**:

```
const https = require('https');
var options = {
    hostname: 'www.legislation.gov.au',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    minVersion: "TLSv1.2",
    maxVersion: "TLSv1.2"
};

https.get(options, response => {
        let body = '';
        response.on('data', d => {
                body += d;
        });
        response.on('end', () => {
                console.log(body);
        });
}).on('error', err => {
        console.error(err);
});
```

I would appreciate any advice that anyone may be able to provide, especially if they can provide a working sample of the request above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try `ciphers: 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0'`**

First, I was able to reproduce with v18.16.0 vs v16.20.0 both in docker -alpine images (which are stable only).

Second, the problem is not version intolerance by the server. Both v16 and v18 *offer* 1.3 by default, and the server negotiates to 1.2 correctly as per RFCs when it doesn't reject. Moreover commandline openssl and curl also offer 1.3 by default and succeed -- but see below. The server identifies itself as IIS/8.5 which is ten years old, and normally runs only on equally old Windows (i.e. 8.1/2012), which didn't support 1.3 at all, so it's probably not 'disabled' just nonexistent.

I find only two differences in the ClientHello between v16 and v18 (and between commandline OpenSSL 1.1.1 and 3.0.x): supported_groups includes the FFDHE groups and sigalgs does NOT include SHA1 schemes.
It appears the latter is the one that matters; if I configure `ciphers:'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0'` (or use commandline equivalent) the SHA1 signatures are added back in, and the handshake succeeds -- even though SHA1 nominally ought to qualify at SECLEVEL=1, plus the server chooses a suite with RSA key exchange which doesn't use ANY signature at all.

Also, a warning: my investigations were delayed quite a bit because the *IPv6* addresses, which some of my test systems preferred, apparently go to a quite different server which responds very differently, although also in AWS and apparently an ELB from the name given.

Comment: OK, marked as accepted. BUT... can you explain why ciphers: ' DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1' did not work? The domains I access are limited so this is probably a reasonable solution, but I don't love dropping down to seclevel=0. Can you provide any information on what I may be giving up? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes SHA1 has nominal strength 80 and one would expect it to work at level 1, as I said; I don't know why it doesn't, and don't have time to debug at the moment. Even at level 0 the default cipherlist doesn't include known-weak ones, so your main concern would probably be a weak cert or weak FFDHE params and per ssllabs neither is a problem on that server. I'd feel more at risk from the obsolete software on the server which probably no longer gets security patches -- if that's any help :-?

Comment: Yup, sounds great. Thanks again for your time, Dave.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76833472/sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-connecting-to-server-using-python-3-11-4-openssl