# SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE connecting to server using Python 3.11.4 + OpenSSL 3.0.9

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to use Python to access a web server (https://legislation.gov.au), but no matter how I customise the SSL context, the handshake fails with the following error.

`ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1002)`

I can connect successfully using `openssl s_client -connect` and a packet capture shows a successful handshake settling on TLS 1.2 (see below).

Versions:
Python 3.11.4 + OpenSSL 3.0.9, OpenSSL 3.1.2

**Steps to replicate:**

```
import ssl, socket
hostname = 'legislation.gov.au'
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
# I've tried other options here too, but we know the server only supports TLS 1.2

context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT')
# Expands the cipher set offered to the server

context.check_hostname=False
context.verify_mode =ssl.CERT_NONE
# It's not important to authenticate the server for the moment.

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_sock = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=hostname)
ssl_sock.connect((hostname, 443))
```

**Troubleshooting steps attempted:**

- define custom ssl context with various protocol values: PROTOCOL_TLS, PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2, etc)
- set context.ciphers = 'DEFAULT'
- test on different platforms: MacOS 13.4.1, Debian 12 (as Docker container on MacOS) (different OpenSSL versions on each platform too)
- try connecting to other servers (handshake succeeds)
- take packet captures of good (openssl CLI) and failed handshakes
- check SSL Labs analysis of server

**Constraints**
I have no influence over the server config, so need to come up with an appropriate SSL context for Python to match the very limited options on the server.

I have just enough knowledge of TLS to be dangerous, so any advice for further troubleshooting or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

**Data**
SSL Labs report shows that the target server only supports TLSv1.2
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=legislation.gov.au&s=54.66.220.183

**PCAP of SUCCESSFUL Client Hello generated by openssl s_client connect**

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
    Length: 282
    Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
        Length: 278
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: 01c9ec3138f46cba4e6a1e10d4d6c55bfe2f1067548516dcf0366e8f79bc4222
            GMT Unix Time: Dec 14, 1970 18:13:37.000000000 AEST
            Random Bytes: 38f46cba4e6a1e10d4d6c55bfe2f1067548516dcf0366e8f79bc4222
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: 64d4842c9c4973138a695997593223de6e5d7027fd0000b1f47cda3ca24cc14e
        Cipher Suites Length: 98
        Cipher Suites (49 suites)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xccaa)
            Cipher Suite: Unknown (0xff85)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x00c4)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0088)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_GOSTR341001_WITH_28147_CNT_IMIT (0x0081)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x00c0)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (0x0084)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00be)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0045)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x00ba)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (0x0041)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc007)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x0005)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x0004)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc012)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc008)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x0016)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0x000a)
            Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
        Compression Methods Length: 1
        Compression Methods (1 method)
            Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 107
        Extension: supported_versions (len=9)
            Type: supported_versions (43)
            Length: 9
            Supported Versions length: 8
            Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.1 (0x0302)
            Supported Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Extension: key_share (len=38)
            Type: key_share (51)
            Length: 38
            Key Share extension
                Client Key Share Length: 36
                Key Share Entry: Group: x25519, Key Exchange length: 32
                    Group: x25519 (29)
                    Key Exchange Length: 32
                    Key Exchange: d7f07ba3b1fe13fb210d6f9e4f9f0b35cef00e2bf795dc5b540ff2453b606b10
        Extension: ec_point_formats (len=2)
            Type: ec_point_formats (11)
            Length: 2
            EC point formats Length: 1
            Elliptic curves point formats (1)
                EC point format: uncompressed (0)
        Extension: supported_groups (len=10)
            Type: supported_groups (10)
            Length: 10
            Supported Groups List Length: 8
            Supported Groups (4 groups)
                Supported Group: x25519 (0x001d)
                Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
        Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
            Type: session_ticket (35)
            Length: 0
            Data (0 bytes)
        Extension: signature_algorithms (len=24)
            Type: signature_algorithms (13)
            Length: 24
            Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 22
            Signature Hash Algorithms (11 algorithms)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512 (0x0806)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (6)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384 (0x0805)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (5)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 (0x0804)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: SM2 (4)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_sha1 (0x0203)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA1 (2)
                    Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
        [JA3 Fullstring [truncated]: 771,4866-4867-4865-49200-49196-49192-49188-49172-49162-159-107-57-52393-52392-52394-65413-196-136-129-157-61-53-192-132-49199-49195-49191-49187-49171-49161-158-103-51-190-69-156-60-47-186-65-49169-49159-5-4-491]
        [JA3: 58d4290faa1ab3429d0ca133e550c375]
```

**PCAP of SUCCESSFUL Server Response to Handshake with openssl s_client -connect**

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
    Content Type: Handshake (22)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 81
    Handshake Protocol: Server Hello
        Handshake Type: Server Hello (2)
        Length: 77
        Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
        Random: 64cb0ef5dad6e262aa8699a4fe855e7efdd90419112893ed5583ab3d7a053c32
            GMT Unix Time: Aug  3, 2023 12:20:37.000000000 AEST
            Random Bytes: dad6e262aa8699a4fe855e7efdd90419112893ed5583ab3d7a053c32
        Session ID Length: 32
        Session ID: d9e0a74c51a6bd68fb2f78e77c58f09a679a991ae84a32cd9e0282dacf36e66f
        Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
        Compression Method: null (0)
        Extensions Length: 5
        Extension: renegotiation_info (len=1)
            Type: renegotiation_info (65281)
            Length: 1
            Renegotiation Info extension
                Renegotiation info extension length: 0
        [JA3S Fullstring: 771,156,65281]
        [JA3S: ccd5709d4a9027ec272e98b9924c36f7]
```

**PCAP of FAILED handshake from Python**

Python's Client Hello appears to be offering at least one cipher that matches the server - 0x009c which is what the server selected for the openssl CLI session:

```
Transport Layer Security
    TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
        Content Type: Handshake (22)
        Version: TLS 1.0 (0x0301)
        Length: 512
        Handshake Protocol: Client Hello
            Handshake Type: Client Hello (1)
            Length: 508
            Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Random: c656166daea9275cecf3491646128ae97978e21a26903155439d3d9675ce6969
                GMT Unix Time: Jun 12, 2075 12:03:25.000000000 AEST
                Random Bytes: aea9275cecf3491646128ae97978e21a26903155439d3d9675ce6969
            Session ID Length: 32
            Session ID: 254f6ecdf88b55a899c5b5f26b10c63ebbf6d3897919f996245dcac83186816b
            Cipher Suites Length: 62
            Cipher Suites (31 suites)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xccaa)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009e)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x006b)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x0067)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0039)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x0033)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x009d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x009c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x003d)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x002f)
                Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
            Compression Methods Length: 1
            Compression Methods (1 method)
                Compression Method: null (0)
            Extensions Length: 373
            Extension: server_name (len=27)
                Type: server_name (0)
                Length: 27
                Server Name Indication extension
                    Server Name list length: 25
                    Server Name Type: host_name (0)
                    Server Name length: 22
                    Server Name: www.legislation.gov.au
            Extension: ec_point_formats (len=4)
                Type: ec_point_formats (11)
                Length: 4
                EC point formats Length: 3
                Elliptic curves point formats (3)
                    EC point format: uncompressed (0)
                    EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_prime (1)
                    EC point format: ansiX962_compressed_char2 (2)
            Extension: supported_groups (len=22)
                Type: supported_groups (10)
                Length: 22
                Supported Groups List Length: 20
                Supported Groups (10 groups)
                    Supported Group: x25519 (0x001d)
                    Supported Group: secp256r1 (0x0017)
                    Supported Group: x448 (0x001e)
                    Supported Group: secp521r1 (0x0019)
                    Supported Group: secp384r1 (0x0018)
                    Supported Group: ffdhe2048 (0x0100)
                    Supported Group: ffdhe3072 (0x0101)
                    Supported Group: ffdhe4096 (0x0102)
                    Supported Group: ffdhe6144 (0x0103)
                    Supported Group: ffdhe8192 (0x0104)
            Extension: session_ticket (len=0)
                Type: session_ticket (35)
                Length: 0
                Data (0 bytes)
            Extension: encrypt_then_mac (len=0)
                Type: encrypt_then_mac (22)
                Length: 0
            Extension: extended_master_secret (len=0)
                Type: extended_master_secret (23)
                Length: 0
            Extension: signature_algorithms (len=42)
                Type: signature_algorithms (13)
                Length: 42
                Signature Hash Algorithms Length: 40
                Signature Hash Algorithms (20 algorithms)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256 (0x0403)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384 (0x0503)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512 (0x0603)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: ed25519 (0x0807)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (7)
                    Signature Algorithm: ed448 (0x0808)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (8)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_pss_sha256 (0x0809)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (9)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_pss_sha384 (0x080a)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (10)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_pss_sha512 (0x080b)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (11)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha256 (0x0804)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: SM2 (4)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha384 (0x0805)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (5)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pss_rsae_sha512 (0x0806)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: Unknown (8)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: Unknown (6)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha256 (0x0401)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha384 (0x0501)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: rsa_pkcs1_sha512 (0x0601)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 ECDSA (0x0303)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: ECDSA (3)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 RSA (0x0301)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: RSA (1)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA224 DSA (0x0302)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA224 (3)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA256 DSA (0x0402)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA256 (4)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA384 DSA (0x0502)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA384 (5)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
                    Signature Algorithm: SHA512 DSA (0x0602)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Hash: SHA512 (6)
                        Signature Hash Algorithm Signature: DSA (2)
            Extension: supported_versions (len=5)
                Type: supported_versions (43)
                Length: 5
                Supported Versions length: 4
                Supported Version: TLS 1.3 (0x0304)
                Supported Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
            Extension: psk_key_exchange_modes (len=2)
                Type: psk_key_exchange_modes (45)
                Length: 2
                PSK Key Exchange Modes Length: 1
                PSK Key Exchange Mode: PSK with (EC)DHE key establishment (psk_dhe_ke) (1)
            Extension: key_share (len=38)
                Type: key_share (51)
                Length: 38
                Key Share extension
                    Client Key Share Length: 36
                    Key Share Entry: Group: x25519, Key Exchange length: 32
                        Group: x25519 (29)
                        Key Exchange Length: 32
                        Key Exchange: 090733685e47a17240dc12a9b84260d6660eca547c229f39ec59c71bfbb24722
            Extension: padding (len=189)
                Type: padding (21)
                Length: 189
                Padding Data: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000…
            [JA3 Fullstring [truncated]: 771,4866-4867-4865-49196-49200-159-52393-52392-52394-49195-49199-158-49188-49192-107-49187-49191-103-49162-49172-57-49161-49171-51-157-156-61-60-53-47-255,0-11-10-35-22-23-13-43-45-51-21,29-23-30-25-24-256-257-]
            [JA3: d39e1be3241d516b1f714bd47c2bc968]
```

Comment: I've been scratching my head on this due to linkchecker reporting errors on links to this exact site! I'm very glad this question was asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This server setup is somewhat broken, as can be seen from the SSLLabs report:

[image: Screenshot from SSLLabs, showing rating A for IPv6 and rating B for IPv4 and also warning about inconsistent setup]

While IPv6 setup is fine the setup for IPv4 is rather different. Details show that no forward secrecy is supported and thus the rating of B only.

On a client which supports both IPv6 and IPv4 it can depend on the program what is actually used to access the server. `openssl s_client` prefers IPv6 and one need to explicitly need to enforce IPv4 with the `-4` option - which promptly shows the handshake to fail in the same way as can be seen in the Python code. The Python code used instead explicitly uses IPv4 (`AF_INET`) - and fails with it.

The reason for the failure is that the client by default <strike>disables any ciphers which don't support forward secrecy</strike> disables SHA1 signatures for security reasons and the server cannot deal with this - see comment on this answer from dave_thompson_085 and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76438852/3081018) to another question for details. The workaround in the client is therefore to downgrade security:

```
context.set_ciphers('DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0')
```

A different workaround is to use IPv6 (`AF_INET6`) instead of IPv4 in the client

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

In any case - the real problem is the broken server setup.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Your explanation makes perfect sense (and of course works!). I had a suspicion the server config was a bit broken, but I can't do anything about it.

Comment: No, (OpenSSL) client default doesn't disable non-forward-secret: see the 6 TLS_RSA_WITH suites shown in the PCAP. The difference SECLEVEL=0 makes is that it allows SHA1 signatures in sigalgs, and that apparently makes the server happy -- even though it doesn't actually use any SHA1 signatures! Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76432102/how-to-force-nodejs-v19-to-use-tls-1-2-to-avoid-write-eproto-ssl-routinesssl3 for a similar case in nodejs.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: thanks for the analysis. I've changed to answer to reflect your input.