# Ignore SSL alert 35: sslv3 alert unsupported certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

I'm trying to use cURL to hit an API on an embedded server (from a Geo satellite modem) which I cannot change. My cURL request succeeds from my Mac with the following version

```
curl 8.1.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) libcurl/8.1.2 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.51.0
Release-Date: 2023-05-30
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe UnixSockets
```

However on my Linux server, I run into SSL alert 35 with the following cURL:

```
curl 7.86.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.86.0 OpenSSL/3.0.7 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.2 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.49.0
Release-Date: 2022-10-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

```
curl -vvvv -L -k https://192.168.44.1/api/
*   Trying 192.168.44.1:443...
* Connected to 192.168.44.1 (192.168.44.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, unsupported certificate (555):
* error:0A000413:SSL routines::sslv3 alert unsupported certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000413:SSL routines::sslv3 alert unsupported certificate
```

My hope was that -k would skip certificate verification altogether, however this alert is still showing up. Is there *any* way to silence, ignore, avoid this OpenSSL error?

Chrome is also refusing to open the page with `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT` (from Mac), though below I can extract the (seemingly) faulty certificate from Firefox:

[image]

Comment: You can't ignore the alert because it's not `curl` that's generating the alert, it's the server. `curl` is just reporting what the server has sent. The server has failed the handshake for the reason indicated. Note the certificate you've displayed is indeed not a proper client certificate since it appears to be a self-signed CA root certificate. Your client certificate may be signed by a certificate that chains to this root but this root is not your client certificate. The whole thing looks puzzling, the curl debug output looks funny, and I don't see where you specify your client certs.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you for the explanation, already helpful. I was hoping I could avoid specifying client certs... the cert I showed is the server's certificate pulled from Firefox via the keypad icon. Is there a way to avoid having to present a client cert? If not, you're suggesting I have to derive a cert from the server's cert and present that to the server?

Comment: @PresidentJ: the `curl` command doesn't have any option to sent a client cert, and moreover the client _can't_ send a cert until after receiving serverhello AND cert AND certreq AND SHdone, which it hasn't. The server is clearly sending a nonsense alert for some reason. If the server device is pretty old and/or cheaply made it might be screwing up because OpenSSL3.0.7 offers 1.3 with extensive options, which also means ClientHello is bigger; I don't know if when or how Mac SecureTransport does. OP: you might try `--tlsv1.2` and/or lower and see if any of those helps.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: my version of curl *does* have an option to send a client cert, according to its man page. `-E` or `--cert`, but I didn't see OP using those options so I was confused.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I have tried --tlsv1.2, 1.0 etc. to no avail unfortunately. I do expect this device to be very old.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: right; the program in general has the option, but I meant the specific command shown in this Q does not use it. Sorry I was ambiguous OP: if you also have commandline OpenSSL you might try `openssl s_client -connect addr:443` with varying versions, ciphers, curves, etc. But in your place I would try to get a network trace of the working case from Mac and compare it to the failing case(s). (Actually I would try to junk the device, but I assume you can't :-()

Comment: @PeterGoldsborough: I recommend that you try `--ciphers 'DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0'` to present to the server (among others) more acceptable signature_algorithms

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that did it, thank you!! Please post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I added CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0 to a custom openssl.cnf in the system_default_sect which I'm passing with the OPENSSL_CONF= to make this usable from software too FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully clear to me what the server is choking about, but it might be that SHA-1 is missing in the signature_algorithms extension. There are servers out there which cannot properly deal with this even if the certificate they offer does not even use SHA-1 - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76438852/3081018) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76834292/3081018) answers for similar observations.

The <strike>fix</strike> work around is like in the referenced answers - use `DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0` as cipher string when connecting to the server.